# How do I keep up with getting trained in multiple skills in a short time?

Tags: job-description, title

Around 3 months back, my company told me to learn a new skill (MEAN stack). I have started working on it. Then the company asked me to learn another skill (Spring Boot). Just as I bought the course for it, the company wants to me to learn yet another skill (C# and ASP.NET). I cannot positively say no to C# + ASP.NET.

While, I love to learn new skills, and that being the primary reason that I love coding, I want to develop one skill for 1-2 years, before hoping onto a new one.

How do I manage to learn multiple skills ?

Update :-

```
Does your company ask you to 
learn these new skills during 
your normal work hours, which they pay you ?
```

Answer - No

I don't mind giving some extra time to study new skill even if it is required by the company. But, I do have a problem, if I have to learn two skills in 3 months while simultaneously working in a different project.

So, I want to know, how do I handle managing to learn multiple skills and working on a project, while not affecting my rating because the manager thinks I am slow.

Comment: Does your company ask you to learn these new skills during your normal work hours, which they pay you ? If yes, then you can think of this as the work they pay you to do. But, if the company asks you to learn the new skills outside the normal work hours, then it is time to start looking for a new job.

Comment: What is the question? How to learn the skills fast? How learn them simultaneously? How to tell your manager that you can't do it / need more time? How to tell your manager that you aren't happy about it?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Well , I wouldn't complain at all, if it were during work hours !!

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Sure do. But, with limited knowledge, it is very difficult to provide quality

Comment: @Asish - so you are required to learn these skills on your own time?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek Yes, except something requires client's approval, in which case, I have free time. It does not happen often though.

Comment: @Asiah can you update your question for more clarity? There were a number of questions asked in the comments. Also, did they explicitly tell you, you should not learn the skills during work time?

Answer (score 10):

I've said it before and I'll say it again: **You're not at work to do what you want to do, you're at work to do what your employer wants you to do**

It's clear your company (I'm guessing some kind of outsourced consultancy?) wants you to work on each of these skills for a short time. If you want to work on one skill for a longer time, you have two options:

1. Talk to your manager and have a discussion about your goals. Maybe there are other projects you can work on which focus on one skill for a longer time.
2. Find a different job which does let you work on one skill for a year or more.

Comment: I have a problem with this "do as you are told" approach. I think it is very important for the OP to understand why these requests are made. I can think a number of reasons this might (but does not have to) raise a red flag. Not wanting to learn more than 2 skills would be the least of my worries. For skilled workers, I think it is important to understand the context, not just so they can make decisions that may further (or mess up) their career, but also decisions for the good of the company. Leaving the decisions to management may work well if management does its job (often not the case).

Answer (score 5):

If you're paying for these course on your own **and** doing the coursework at night, you are allowing yourself to be abused.

You sound, with all due respect, young and inexperienced.  If the company values these skills they want you to learn, they'll make an investment by allowing you to learn them during work hours, and *maybe* paying for training if there's not enough material online for you to learn from in an efficient manner.  But they're betting on your inexperience, and this is *why* they can make demands such as you learning all these skills at once.

The technologies you've mentioned are far enough to learn *separately* but as you're sensing, you're not going to gain any real proficiency in the way the company wants you to proceed.

Comment: "You sound, with all due respect, young and inexperienced." - Obviously :). Otherwise, I would not have asked this in Stackoverflow